# Sitecore 8.1 computed index field for image only indexing alt text on solr

Tags: indexing, solr, sitecore, sitecore8, computed-field

Ran into this issue the other day but can't find anything yet (from googling) that addresses this issue.

I am using Solr as my indexing engine. I am trying to index a image field in my template. Indexing is working fine but it's not indexing the media URL (that I am returning from my code) instead it's indexing the ALT text of the image. If the ALT text is not present only then it's indexing the media URL. 
I have my index configuration in a separate file.

I think the below line in the default Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config file is probably messing with my config. But how do I overwrite this only for "main_image" field.

```xml
<fieldReader fieldTypeName="image" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.ImageFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
```

Below is how my configuration looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <myindex>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <mySolrIndexConfiguration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration">
            <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
                <field fieldName="main_image" returnType="text">My.Indexing.Namespace.MyMainImageIndexing,My.Indexing</field>
                <field fieldName="thumbnail" returnType="text">My.Indexing.Namespace.MyThumbnailIndexing,My.Indexing</field>
            </fields>
        </mySolrIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </myindex>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

One of the implementations looks like below (the other one is similar)

```cs
public class MyMainImageIndexing : IComputedIndexField
{
    public string Parameters { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string ReturnType { get; set; }

    public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(indexable, "indexable");
        var indexableItem = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;

        if (indexableItem == null)
        {
            Log.Warn(string.Format("{0} : unsupported IIndexable type : {1}", this, indexable.GetType()), this);
            return null;
        }

        ImageField img = indexableItem.Item.Fields["Main Image"];

        return (img == null || img.MediaItem == null) ? null : MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(img.MediaItem);
    }
}
```

Could anyone please shed some light here on how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

P.S> I have seen John West's post here http://www.sitecore.net/de-de/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/05/sitecore-7-pre-render-image-fields.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks completely fine. You have a bug in your configuration.

You set `returnType` of your fields to `text` which means that Solr will tokenize those fields. It means that Solr won't keep the values as a one string, instead it will create tokens which would allow full text search in the future.

You should change your configuration to

```xml
<field fieldName="main_image" returnType="string">...
```

After you reindex, Solr will keep the whole value as a single string.

Also you should be aware that if you rename a media item, Solr will have outdated urls and it will not rebuild all the referencing documents automatically.